# How to create, send and close button and update the status field in view

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

[image]

**My button name : Sign and send to hrd**

Previously I have used this code, it is working for sending mail with doclink and update status field in a view and after after typing password the form send to hrd dept and close automatically.

**Here:**

1.Sanlotus is my server name

2.The empmaster is my employe details NSF

3.Master is  view in empmaster.nsf

4.CPDname is a Richtext field, it is updated with officer's name automatically from view master.

5.CPDdesg is also a richtext field, it is updated with officer designation automatically from view master.

6.status is a computed field.

7.hrd is also computed field (It is code is staffhrd@san.org"email address")

**NOW I WANT TO CREATE THIS TYPE OF BUTTON IN XPAGES **

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Please post your Xpage code

Answer (score 0):

Some key @Functions you're using there are not available in XPages, see http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/List_of_Formula_Not_Supported_In_XPages.

It's not possible with @Formula code.

It seems you've come from a Notes Client development background. Think about how you would achieve this with LotusScript in a back-end agent (no UI LotusScript classes are available in XPages).

Where you put the resulting code will depend a lot on the XPage you're trying to build.